# How to create client secret for Azure Service Principal using Terraform

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, terraform, terraform-provider-azure, azure-service-principal

I am fairly new in Azure and Terraform, and am trying to create a secret client for Azure Service Principal using Terraform.
I am unable to figure this out.

This is what I have right now:

```
provider "azuread" {
  version = "=0.7.0"
  client_id = var.aws_client_id
  subscription_id = var.aws_subscription_id
  tenant_id = var.aws_tenant_id
  client_secret = var.aws_client_secret
}

# Create an application
resource "azuread_application" "app" {
  name = var.azurerd_app_name
}

# Create a service principal
resource "azuread_service_principal" "app" {
  application_id = azuread_application.app.application_id
}
```

This is what I was trying(Not very sure about it):

```
resource "random_string" "password" {
  length  = 32
  special = true
}

# Create Service Principal password
resource "azuread_service_principal_password" "app" {
  end_date             = "2299-12-30T23:00:00Z"                        # Forever
  service_principal_id = azuread_service_principal.app.id
  value                = random_string.password.result
}
```

This, obviously, doesn't work. This is not giving any error, but, no secret is visible on Azure console. Looks like this is for attaching some password to service principal but I am not very sure what it is doing.

Please let me know what could be done regarding this. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Actually, `azuread_service_principal_password` worked well, but the password did not show in the portal.

You could use [`azuread_application_password`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/azuread/r/application_password.html) to manage a Password associated with an Application within Azure AD. see the **NOTE**, make sure the application have the permissions mentioned.

Comment: Does the service principal even show up for you in the Azure portal? I can't find it. I have to use `terraform output` to get the password when I have this
`resource "azuread_service_principal_password" "app" {
  service_principal_id = azuread_service_principal.app.id
}

output "sp_password" {
  value     = azuread_service_principal_password.app.value
  sensitive = true
}`

Comment: I believe the link is now [azuread_application_password](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azuread/latest/docs/resources/application_password).

Answer (score 3):

The client secret for the service principle created in your example will work. The client secret will have the value of `random_string.password.result` as you're assigning that to `azuread_service_principal_password.app.value` which is the client secret.

If you'd like to output the client secret to the console to see it, you can either create a terraform output:

```
output "client_secret" {
  value = random_string.password.result
  sensitive = false # Note that you might not want to print this in out in the console all the time
}
```

You can also ask whenever you wish for terraform to print out the value from its state:

```
$ terraform state show random_string.password.result
```

Answer (score 0):

You can let Terraform and Azure create the password for you and then use `terraform output` to retrieve it. You probably want it to be marked as **sensitive** though.

```
# Create Azure AD App Registration
resource "azuread_application" "app" {
  display_name = "my-app"
}

# Create Service Principal
resource "azuread_service_principal" "app" {
  application_id = azuread_application.app.application_id
}

# Create Service Principal password
resource "azuread_service_principal_password" "app" {
  service_principal_id = azuread_service_principal.app.id
}

# Output the Service Principal and password
output "sp" {
  value     = azuread_service_principal.app.id
  sensitive = true
}

output "sp_password" {
  value     = azuread_service_principal_password.app.value
  sensitive = true
}
```

Then `terraform output sp_password` will get it for you and you won't have it getting printed out to the console on every `plan` and `apply`.